# ftp_nlist() returns false even with ftp_pasv() set

Tags: list, ftp

I'm writing a little script to list all the files I have in a distant ftp folder. Unfortunately, I have a bool(false) each time I try...

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $port);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
var_dump($contents);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I saw that there was an issue with var_dump()and ftp_nlist(), but regarding the manual it could be fixed by putting the server in passive mode with ftp_pasv(), in my case I still got a bool(false)error. I cannot figure out why...

Any help will be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you access the specific target host from the same source host using some other FTP software? If not than it might simply be that firewalls or the network architecture (like both sites behind NAT) prevent the access. FTP is known to play badly with any kind of firewalls, NAT etc.

Comment: I can access with my FTP client, and I can even get a list with `ftp_rawlist()`

Comment: The `ftp_nlist` should issue a PHP warning when something goes wrong. Do you get any?

Comment: So if you replace the `ftp_nlist` with `ftp_rawlist`, it works, even if you keep the rest of the code intact?

Comment: Can you show us a network capture (e.g. using Wireshark) for both cases?

Comment: Exactly! But I figured out that is wasn't the script. I tested it on another ftp server and it worked perfectly. It seems that the ftp server wasn't accepting `ftp_nlist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that is wasn't the script. I tested it on another ftp server and it worked perfectly. It seems that the ftp server wasn't accepting `ftp_nlist()`